# Insert additional text into table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I export a CSV-File with shipping weights from my webshop. The problem is there are bulk numbers and no unit Like this:

```
+------+------+
| ID   |weight|
+------+------+
| 101  | 1,2  |
+------+------+
| 102  | 2,5  |
+------+------+
```

But I need a result like this:

```
+------+------+
| ID   |weight|
+------+------+
| 101  |1,2 kg|
+------+------+
| 102  |2,5 kg|
+------+------+
```

This is the statement:

```
SELECT id_product AS `ID`, weight AS `weight` FROM products
```

Is it possible to add a string ('kg') into the SELECT statement or something of a kind? Or are there other possible solutions?
(The system works with SELECT only)

Comment: I'd consider a separate unit column instead.

Comment: Unfortunately it's necessary to have it in the same column...

Comment: Note that `2,5 kg > 100,0 kg`, if you compare varchar/char data.

Comment: doesn't matter. it's for a google feed and need to have this syntax...
but thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below query.

```
SELECT id_product AS `ID`, CONCAT(weight ,' kg') AS `weight` FROM products
```

Hope will help you

Comment: very simple but effective. I saw CONCAT in the mysql documentation but I didn't perceive it as solution...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT id_product AS `ID`, weight || ' Kg' AS `weight` FROM products
```

You can also use CONCAT() function instead.